# Decipher this capacitor's label?

Tags: capacitor, identification

Yes, I'm a noob. I am trying, please be nice.

I am trying to test the parts on an LED driver that's gone bad. Mainly because I actually NEED the thing to work, but also so I can learn how to do this sort of thing.

Mains in to a fuse (which is fine), then to this film capacitor. Multimeter on CAP setting gives me 125.5 nanofarads. (Why the meter doesn't auto-adjust to uF is yet another mystery, but that's another question.)

I can use the label info from the SIDE to find this document:
https://www.pcb-3d.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/CAPRR_EPCOS_B32921-B32926_SERIES.pdf

Below the legible printed info on the side there are only the 'reversed LR' symbols and the 'EN over EC' symbol.

On page 3 you'll find the match for the series, but showing 6 uF variations. None of the six values make sense to me as a match for what I measured with the multimeter.

I know that I am meant to use the info from the TOP label to figure out the proper farad value,  but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do that.

Some of it's obvious - 305V A/C. But the rest of the info doesn't seem to match the info in that doc? I am really confused by this.

If you can just tell me the value, great. That's enough to let me know if it's the .10 uF version and my .1255 uF actual measure is close  -  or if my actual measure is way off what it is supposed to be.

But if you can also explain how I'm meant to translate the label that'd be way better.

Phrased as proper questions:

What capacitance is the pictured capacitor?

AND

How does one use the text on the label to determine the capacitance?

[image][image: CapTop]

Comment: "B1-U1" almost matches the top-right example. 0.1255uF is a bit out of spec for "M" though.

Comment: Did you desolder it before measuring its capacitance? You can't trust capacitance measurements made in-circuit, generally.

Comment: @Felthry Desolder it? No. Must I? There's like ten box-shaped capacitors on here, and I've never desoldered anything before. Plan was to ID bad parts, cut them off and use jumper wires from their cutoff legs to install new parts. YES it's a lame way to do anything, but I don't think myself capable of actually desoldering and resoldering on the board itself.

Comment: I saw the 105 code on the side which means it should be a 1.0 uF X2 rated capacitor. If it measures 10% of that then this capacitor has oxidized and is useless. Safe-but useless.

Comment: The side codes are env. temp. the part value is not shown. THe lead space and dimensions in mm will tell me though e.g. some 0.1uF are 6.0w × 15.0h × 26.5l.  20% tolerance is normal

Comment: It is unlikely this X2 cap is at fault... very reliable parts, check transistors

Comment: @Nixt You don't know what you're measuring if you leave it in-circuit. There could be all kinds of junk in parallel with the capacitor that could mess up your reading.

Comment: @Nixt. *You will get nowhere unless you pull out parts*, even just one lead, and check them independently. I do NOT believe an X2 capacitor has failed open. It would not stop the circuit from working if it did fail.

Comment: Can I redirect the commenters to the question, please? I'm asking about how to translate/decipher the top label info to determine the rating. I'm grateful for the input about my inaccurate testing method and the likelihood of this item being bad, but I still really want to understand how to take the info that's on the thing and use it against the info in the document I found to be able to say "it is a <value goes here> uF capacitor".

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt - lead spacing is 10mm on the board but 15mm on the underside of the blue box (they 'dog-leg' underneath the part). Overall length about 17, height about 12, width is spot on 5mm. I can't exactly get a calliper on it to get any more precise on the ht and lgth...

Comment: INFO: Have a local uni student looking at it. He just texted me to tell me it's all working to just past the bridge rectifier, which means this cap is not faulty. Still want to know how to read/identify it though, please?

Comment: The value may be below your photo, the rest is for traceability and environmental limits and family type , the datasheet will tell the values for that size as they are limited to a couple values. The buck switcher is dead perhaps from excessive heat rise or faulty short circuit connections with inductive kick back or power line transients. Probe and compare IC waveforms on each pin.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt - edited the question to include that below the visible and legible text in the 'side' picture there are only the backward-printed LR symbols and the EN over EC symbol.

Answer (score 2):

That is an X-type safety capacitor).

Printed on the side:

MKP/SH: denotes polypropylene film dielectric, self-healing

B32921:  denotes the case size; this case size is typically rated 305VAC.

40/105/56: Climatic Code from IEC 60068-1, interpreted as follows, obtained from [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/26033/gentechinfofilm.pdf)

> CLIMATIC CATEGORY The  climatic  category  indicates  the  climatic 
>   conditions   which   the   capacitor   may   be   operated.
>   According   to    IEC 60068-1 the climatic category is expressed by a
>   three  group coding e.g. 55/100/56.
>   -  The first group indicates the lower category temperature  (- 55 °C).
>   -  The   second   group   the   upper   category   temperature    (+ 100 °C).
>   -  The third group indicates th e number of days (56) which  the  capacitor  can  withstand  within  specified  limits  if   exposed to
>   a relative humidity of 95 % and a temperature  of + 40 °C.

I suspect if you can view the rest of the component markings you will find the capacitance, tolerance, and probably the voltage.

Comment: As in posted question:"If you can just tell me the value, great. ... But if you can also explain how I'm meant to translate the label that'd be way better." I already understand that the other markings will somehow code the capacitance - this is exactly what I seek help with.

Comment: Just thinking about how I didn't use a question mark in the original to clearly indicate where the dual-part question is. I will edit the question to include fully formed questions with question marks.